# How to copy images (such as albums) on the local disk to the image tag？

Tags: react-native

RN Chinese online said image tags can be directly displayed on the local disk (such as albums), how to set up？
https://reactnative.cn/docs/image/

Comment: like this:    <image  source={'here, read the local disk (such as albums)'}/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the phone read and write permissions and camera permissions. Set as follows:

```html
<Image style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} source={{ uri: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/crop_20a7dc7fbd29d679b456fa0f77bd9525d.jpg'}} />
```

The same is true for the video: image gets the first frame of the video

```html
<Image style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} source={{ uri: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/tencent/MicroMsg/WeiXin/1534588747082.mp4'}} />
```